# How does tractor achieve constant PTO speed?

Tags: automotive-engineering, power-transmission, transmission

Tractors have a PTO shaft which supplies power to implements. Most implements are rated 540 or 1000 RPM.

I'd like to know more about transmission that is used to convert variable motor shaft rotation to constant PTO rotation? If you can give me a hint about the right search keywords, that would be great.

Comment: Search for CVT, continuously variable transmission

Comment: PTO is relative to engine speed.  To get 540 or 1000, you run the engine at a set speed.  No one is putting a transmission or variable output on a PTO to account for engine speed.  You just run the engine at the speed you need.  Bush hogs don't care what speed they run.

Comment: Apart from constant engine speed a hydraulic drive can be used.